# Angular Asyc - Which layer would need to be turned into the class that has the async methods?

Tags: angular

How do I convert this code to be async? i have dumbed down the actual code for essentially what is on - essentially, do I convert the service layer to be async or the utils libary?

I have a component that has basic field to display on the page:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {UserInfomrationServiceService} from '../user-infomration-service.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-user-information',
      templateUrl: './user-information.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./user-information.component.css']
    })
    export class UserInformationComponent implements OnInit {

      private userService: UserInfomrationServiceService;
      private userID: number;
      private userAge: number;
      private userShoeSize: number;
      private userSiblingcount: number;
      constructor(private userInformationService: UserInfomrationServiceService) {
        this.userService = userInformationService;
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.getUserAge().subscribe(x => this.userID = x);
        this.userService.getUserID().subscribe(x => this.userAge = x);
        this.userService.getUserShoeSize().subscribe(x => this.userShoeSize = x);
        this.userService.getUserSiblingCount().subscribe(x => this.userSiblingcount = x);
      }
    }
```

this consumes a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {UtilSimpleTypeApiService} from './util-simple-type-api.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserInfomrationServiceService {

  private util: UtilSimpleTypeApiService;
  constructor(private utilObj: UtilSimpleTypeApiService) {
    this.util = utilObj;
  }

   getUserSiblingCount(): Observable<number> {
    return this.util.getNumberType();
  }
  getUserShoeSize(): Observable<number> {
    return this.util.getNumberType();
  }

  getUserID(): Observable<number> {
    return this.util.getNumberType();
  }

  getUserAge(): Observable<number> {
    return this.util.getNumberType();
  }
}
```

which calls a hard coded random integer generator for the sake of testing:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UtilSimpleTypeApiService {

  constructor(private httpClinet: HttpClient) { }

  getNumberType(): Observable<number> {
    return this.httpClinet.get<number>('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10000&col=5&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new');
  }
}
```

should i add async to the helper or the servicE?

Comment: Why do you want to add async in the first place ?

Comment: @Florian I need to get 6 separate single fields from 6 different api routes.

Comment: http requests are all async, your whole code is asynchronous. Congrats.. however if you indent to use results, post all apis have results you can use [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Comment: I think you might misunderstand how angular `HttpClient` and `rxjs` observables work. You don't need async/await mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Base on what I understand on your comments you can actually.

I have two suggestion

1. `Promises`

   - By converting all your observables to `Promise`

Example:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    // always put a catch when doing async/await because it will throw and the code execution will stop.

    const userAge = await this.userService.getUserAge().toPromise().catch(x => null);
    this.userAge = userAge;

    const userID = await this.userService.getUserID().toPromise().catch(x => null);
    this.userID = userID;

    const userShoeSize = await this.userService.getUserShoeSize().toPromise().catch(x => null);
    this.userShoeSize = userShoeSize;

    const userSiblingcount = await this.userService.getUserSiblingCount().toPromise().catch(x => null);
    this.userSiblingcount = userSiblingcount;
}
```

2. By using RxJS operator `forkJoin`

Example:

```
ngOnInit() {
   const result = forkJoin(
      this.userService.getUserAge(),
      this.userService.getUserID(),
      this.userService.getUserShoeSize(),
      this.userService.getUserSiblingCount()
    );
   result.subsribe((res: any[]) => {
     this.userAge = res[0];
     this.userID = res[1];
     this.userShoeSize = res[2];
     this.userSiblingcount = res[3];
   });
 }
```

Take note in the `forkJoin` there might be some error calls, so I will leave it up to you.